# Selector for element inside a frame (with same origin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, frames

I have a webpage with the following structure:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<frameset>
<frame name="frame1" src="/index.jsp"/>
<frame name="frame2" src="/blank.jsp"/>
</frameset>
</html>
```

`index.jsp` contains:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
... <div id="test">test is here</div> ...
</body>
</html>
```

I need a jQuery selector to directly access `div#test`. So far I've only been able to write it like this: `$(frames[0].document.body)` ...or this: `$("frame[name='frame1']")`. But I have a template which requires me to write my selector inside `$("here only")`. So I can't use `.find()` or other functions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
$("div#test", $("#someIFrame").contents())
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, this appears to work for iframes as well as frames

Answer (score 1):

yeah I got it. thanks.

This is what I wrote.

```
$("div[id='test'] > span",frames['frame1'].document).text()
```