# Nested iframes, AKA Iframe Inception

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Using jQuery I am trying to access div id="element".

```
<body>
    <iframe id="uploads">
        <iframe>
            <div id="element">...</div>
        </iframe>
    </iframe>
</body>
```

All iframes are on the same domain with no www / non-www issues.

I have successfully selected elements within the first iframe but not the second nested iframe.

I have tried a few things, this is the most recent (and a pretty desperate attempt).

```
var iframe = jQuery('#upload').contents();
var iframeInner = jQuery(iframe).find('iframe').contents();
var iframeContent = jQuery(iframeInner).contents().find('#element');

// iframeContent is null
```

Edit:
To rule out a timing issue I used a click event and waited a while.

```
jQuery().click(function(){
   var iframe = jQuery('#upload').contents().find('iframe');
   console.log(iframe.find('#element')); // [] null
});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Update:
I can select the second iframe like so...

```
var iframe = jQuery('#upload').contents().find('iframe');
```

The problem now seems to be that the src is empty as the iframe is generated with javascript.
So the iframe is selected but the content length is 0.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: this probably isn't useful but I can't help but wonder *why* you want to manipulate a twice nested iframe document... how did you get here?  Possible XY problem.

Comment: I am creating a DRM application which uses CKFinder with Amazon S3. It is CKFinder that I am trying to alter.
I have made vast changes to functionality but it is now the UI that I need to change. (which can't be changed with CSS as there a multiple instances that don't need this specific alteration)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473557/jquery-selector-for-element-inside-frame-with-same-origin

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1654262/1813169) answer, you must link to jQuery inside each `iframe` in which you want to use DOM traversal.  In your case, `uploads` must therefore contain `<script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js"></script>` or similar.

Comment: iframe Inception!

Answer (score 60):

Thing is, the code you provided won't work because the `<iframe>` element has to have a "src" property, like:

```
<iframe id="uploads" src="http://domain/page.html"></iframe>
```

It's ok to use `.contents()` to get the content:

`$('#uploads).contents()` will give you access to the second iframe, but if that iframe is "INSIDE" the `http://domain/page.html` document the #uploads iframe loaded.

To test I'm right about this, I created 3 html files named main.html, iframe.html and noframe.html and then selected the div#element just fine with:

```
$('#uploads').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#element');
```

There WILL be a delay in which the element will not be available since you need to wait for the iframe to load the resource. Also, all iframes have to be on the same domain.

Hope this helps ...

Here goes the html for the 3 files I used (replace the "src" attributes with your domain and url):

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>main.html example</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            console.log( $('#uploads').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#element') ); // nothing at first

            setTimeout( function () {
                console.log( $('#uploads').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#element') ); // wait and you'll have it
            }, 2000 );

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="uploads" src="http://192.168.1.70/test/iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iframe.html example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://192.168.1.70/test/noframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

noframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>noframe.html example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="element">some content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: My bad. You can actually go without a "src" attribute on an iframe and write code with just javascript:

`<script>
myHTML = '<p>you should write complete and proper html here, including the html, head and body tags</p>';
myFrame = document.getElementById("uploads").contentDocument;
myFrame.open();
myFrame.write(myHTML);
myFrame.close();
</script>`

Comment: This worked for me. And I have no ID anywhere. I had to play with classes :)

Comment: @CarlosCastillo, Thanks very much. It solved my problem with iframe inside bootstrap modal as well. I'm looking way to change element inside iframe, but my function to do that was always loading before iframe fully loaded. Waiting for a few second is a solution. Thanks again for useful answer, I vote up 1+ :)

Answer (score 13):

`var iframeInner = jQuery(iframe).find('iframe').contents();`

`var iframeContent = jQuery(iframeInner).contents().find('#element');`

iframeInner contains elements from

```
<div id="element">other markup goes here</div>
```

and iframeContent will find for elements which are inside of

```
 <div id="element">other markup goes here</div>
```

(find doesn't search on current element) that's why it is returning null.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I got something that seems to be doing what you want a do. It involves some dirty copying but works. You can find the working code [here](http://champi.alwaysdata.net/Test.html)

So here is the main html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            Iframe = $('#frame1');

            Iframe.on('load', function(){
                IframeInner = Iframe.contents().find('iframe');

                IframeInnerClone = IframeInner.clone();

                IframeInnerClone.insertAfter($('#insertIframeAfter')).css({display:'none'});

                IframeInnerClone.on('load', function(){
                    IframeContents = IframeInner.contents();

                    YourNestedEl = IframeContents.find('div');

                    $('<div>Yeepi! I can even insert stuff!</div>').insertAfter(YourNestedEl)
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="insertIframeAfter">Hello!!!!</div>
    <iframe id="frame1" src="Test_Iframe.html">

    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, once the first Iframe is loaded, I get the second one and clone it. I then reinsert it in the dom, so I can get access to the onload event. Once this one is loaded, I retrieve the content from non-cloned one (must have loaded as well, since they use the same src). You can then do wathever you want with the content.

Here is the Test_Iframe.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Test_Iframe</div>
    <iframe src="Test_Iframe2.html">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Test_Iframe2.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>I am the second nested iframe</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a timing issue. Your document.ready commend is probably firing before the the second iFrame is loaded.  You dont have enough info to help much further- but let us know if that seems like the possible issue.

Comment: I don't think it's a timing issue. Trying to find the element on a click event after a minute still returns null. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should use live method for elements which are rendered later, like colorbox, hidden fields or iframe

```
$(".inverter-value").live("change",function() {
     elem = this
    $.ajax({
      url: '/main/invertor_attribute/',
      type: 'POST',
      aysnc: false,
      data: {id: $(this).val() },
      success: function(data){
       // code
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to reach your div:

```
var your_element=$('iframe#uploads').children('iframe').children('div#element');
```

It should work well.

Comment: $('iframe').children('div') doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If browser supports iframe, then DOM inside iframe come from src attribute of respective tag. Contents that are inside iframe tag are used as a fall back mechanism where browser does not supports iframe tag.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that jQuery is not loaded in your iframes.

The safest approach is to rely on pure DOM-based methods to parse your content.

Or else, start with jQuery, and then once inside your iframes, test once if `typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined'`, if it's true, jQuery is not enabled inside it and fallback on DOM-based method.