# Jquery iframe to find and replace content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a single page website which includes an iframe in it, when iframe load it contains a table which I want to hide and this table also repeats on multiple pages so I want to add a code in my main page header which finds this content from iframe and hide it if even iframes loads new pages the code which I want to hide is

```
<table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="225"><a id="_ctl0_ucMNB_logo_LogoHyperLink" href="#"><img id="_ctl0_ucMNB_logo_imgLeftPart" class="header_logo_img" src="#" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Refer this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe?
rq=1

Comment: Is the iFrame src in the same domain as the main page?

Comment: You should urgently improve your question to make it clearer...

Comment: If you give the table a specific id, you can select the content of the iframe like the answer below and then select the table from it and delete it: `.contents().$('#idyougavetothetable').remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.contents()` to get the content of the iframe and do the operation on it, 
For more details 
https://api.jquery.com/contents/

[jQuery, select element inside iframe, which is inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343955/jquery-select-element-inside-iframe-which-is-inside-iframe)

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
var f=$('body')
f.load(function(){ 
 f.contents().find('#_ctl0_ucMNB_logo_LogoHyperLink').html("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>This IS an iframe</h1>");
 f.contents().find( "#_ctl0_bodyTag" ).css( "background-image", "none" ); 
})
})
}, 5000);
</script>` even after the iframe loads the new page clicking on link this code not work please help

Comment: @user1393638, can you make a fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/ of your code, will look

Comment: here is the fiddle which i have http://jsfiddle.net/C9Ly4/ when we click on some link present in iframe it loads new pages, which contains div #_ctl0_ucMNB_logo_LogoHyperLink and #_ctl0_bodyTag which i want to remove but this code done remove these tags please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

$('iframe').contents().find('control');