# Selecting tags from inside an iframe with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to select an html5 video element from inside an embedded ifame
(specifically the video element generated from embedding a youtube video).
I know that I want to use the $("video") selector to grab the element, but since it is in an iframe It is more complex.

I found that the .contents() method will spill out the iframe contents
([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343955/jquery-select-element-inside-iframe-which-is-inside-iframe))
However, the request gets blocked because it is a cross-origin request.

here is the DOM error I get after trying the .contents() method:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Error (native)
    at m.each.contents (file:///home/alex/Desktop/kiosk/Client/jquery.js:2:26679)
    at Function.m.extend.map (file:///home/alex/Desktop/kiosk/Client/jquery.js:2:3714)
    at m.each.m.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (file:///home/alex/Desktop/kiosk/Client/jquery.js:2:26777)
    at <anonymous>:2:9
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)`

Any Ideas to fix or work around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: Check out the stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame