# hide pop-out in google docs viewer using javascript-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, ms-word, display

I am using google docs viewer to display word and PDF files in dialog in my application. But my client need that document should not get download. So want to hide 'Pop-out' option. Please help me for it. Below is my code snippet :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnShow").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: '',
                width: 750,
                height: 450,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }                   
                },
                open: function () {
                    var object = "<iframe id='resViewer' src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=my_file.pdf&embedded=true' style='width: 700px; height: 700px;' frameborder='0'></iframe>";                    

                    $("#dialog").html(object);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Show PDF" />
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Please help me.

If anyone knows any other way to display word and PDF file both give me way or suggest for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You could stop the pop out button from displaying with the CSS rule `display: none`.

Comment: Can you please help me for that. I am not able to hide it.

Comment: Oh wow, Google is using class names like ndfHFb-c4YZDc-MZArnb-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe making everything difficult. Why is your client so against others downloading his PDFs? There already out on the web for everyone to see, I don't see what's so bad about a person having a local copy of the PDF that they can print out and review.

Comment: @Mr.Me , So there is no way to hide that button? :(

Answer (score -1):

The following CSS will remove the pop out button.

```
div[aria-label="Pop-out"] {
    display: none;
}
div["aria-label=toolbar"] {
    width: 52px;
}
```

But to get the CSS to apply to the iframe your going to have to do some trickery. See [jQuery, select element inside iframe, which is inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343955/jquery-select-element-inside-iframe-which-is-inside-iframe) and [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe#answer-19392394)

Comment: I have set this in style tag like this : <style>
div[aria-label=Pop-out] {
    display: none;
}
div[aria-label=toolbar] {
    width: 52px;
}
</style>  But this is not working. Please tell me where to set it?

Comment: So I just opened up a Google Doc, and went to file publish, and the embed code that they gave me does not have a download link. See this fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/kaagvxLb/ Also when I clicked on share and then advanced there was an option at the bottom to prevent downloading, printing, and copying.

Comment: Here I am using file which is stored to Azure Blob storage. A PDF and word file. Can you please guide me for it.

Comment: I forgot that CSS won't affect iframes. You'll have to dynamically append a stylesheet to the iframe with JavaScript. See the following question on how to do this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: I tried to create a fiddle of this, but this is as far as I could get. https://jsfiddle.net/b3x26Lst/2/ But if you don't have too many files you're dealing with, there is an option in Google Docs to prevent downloading a file. Also In the SO question In the last comment I posted many of the answers won't work anymore because of cors policies. I updated the answer with a better question you can view.