# How to hide status bar in Microsoft office online viewer

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, pdf, iframe

My client need view only office viewer(doc,docx,ppt etc..). I tried to convert Docs to PDF in java(using apache poi and doc4j) and show it using pdf viewer.But results are not so much perfect.The converted pdf file does not render images and tables correctly as it was in document.So i thought of using Microsoft office viewer online and hide the status bar which provide download button and print button and hence make it view only.But i couldn't access the dom elements inside iframe. Is there any better way to handle this problem or suggest any solution to convert office files to pdf or to any image formats.

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

This is code for embedding live office viewer in html.

I also tried

```
<iframe id='resViewer' src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx&embedded=true' style='width: 700px; height: 700px;' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

In this case i cannot hide Pop-Out Button.i referred many post in stack overflow itself but none of that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this [hide popout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147063/hide-pop-out-in-google-docs-viewer-using-javascript-jquery)

```
div[aria-label="Pop-out"] {
display: none;
 }
 //syntax
div[aria-label="toolbar"] {
width: 52px;
}
```