# altering contents inside iframe and remove unwanted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div

```
<div id="container">
<iframe id="survey" src="somepage"></iframe>
</div>
```

Now the page loads inside the iframe

I want to remove all the other items except a div inside the iframe

```
$("#container").html($("#survey .requiredDiv").html())
```

But this is not working

Is it possible to do such thing? What should be done?

Comment: Have you tried using `contents()` instead?
`var frame = $('#survey').contents();`

Comment: Have you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15556150/7599559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember: The `src` of `iframe` should also have to be in the same domain. This is due to security reasons.

Yet you can use load/html such way:

```
$("#container").html(function(){
    // There could be multiple target elements, i guess you should loop and return the html
    var htm = '';
    $("#survey").contents().find(".requiredDiv").each(function(){
       htm += this;  
    });
    return htm;
});
```

using `.load()`:

```
$("#container").load($("#survey").contents().find(".requiredDiv"));
```