# How to choose the value of an a > href tag within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, href

I want to **choose the value** of an **a > href** tag within an **iframe**
This page is my code but it does **not work.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addl_ads iframe').attr('id', "ads_frame");
     </script> 

     <iframe src="iframe.html" width="468" height="60"></iframe>

       <button onclick="dd()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function dd() {
    var x =  $('#ads_frame').contents().find('body').find('a').find('href');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
    </script>
```

please help

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556150/2298362

Comment: `.find('href')` trys to find an element named href, eg `<href>`, if you meant to get the value of the href attribute of the anchor element you would do `.attr('href')`

Comment: @PatrickEvans You can correct this code

Comment: @PrabodhM not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved. I had to try it on local host ! :D