# I have page inside page and i want to get div from inner page and inner page have iframe through jquery selector. Not iframe inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to get any data from div which have id wrapper.
I am struck at this point need your right answer.
[image: here is more complete detail of my problem]
How I can get data from that div by using jQuery selector.

```js
function savehtml(){
  var iframe=$("#gjs-cv-canvas").contents().find("iframe").contents().find("#wrapper").html();
  alert(iframe);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body >
            <button onclick="savehtml()">save</button>
            <div id="gjs">
            <div class="gjs-editor">
            <div id="gjs-cv-canvas">
             <iframe class="gjs-frame">
                 <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body class="gjs-dashed">
                <div id="wrapper">
              
                 <div>abc</div>
                 <div>abc</div>
                 
                 </div>
                 </body>
                 </html>
             </iframe>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, select element inside iframe, which is inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343955/jquery-select-element-inside-iframe-which-is-inside-an-iframe)

Comment: i have page inside page and inner page have iframe