# how do you get a data attribute that is inside an iframe with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I am trying to get a data attribute from an element that is inside an iframe. This iframe is inside our website. So, when I click on the next button I have a callback that has the following code.

```
onNext : function(){
   var $img = $(".tacobowl").contents().find(".url").data('img');
   var $imgFolder = $(".tacobowl").contents().find(".url").data('imgFolder');
   alert($img + ' ' + $imgFolder);    
},
```

This code returns an alert box that says "undefined undefined".

The class `taco` is attached to the `<iframe class="taco"></iframe>`

Then this is the html inside the iframe.

```
<div class="url" data-img="small" data-imgFolder="breakfast">

</div>
```

I have been able to add classes by using the following code. But, I have not been able to get the data attribute from this same div.

```
  $(".tacobowl").contents().find(".url").addClass("taco100");
```

Is it even possible to get the data attribute in such a way?

Comment: How to select the data attributes is well answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute

If you will provide more details of the abstract html structure in your page, you will get solution quicker. It is unclear here what is `taco` class bind with.

Comment: Alright if `taco` class is for `iframe` as you have mentioned in below answer comment, selecting element inside iframe is answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343955/jquery-select-element-inside-iframe-which-is-inside-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`$('.url',$(".taco").contents()).data('img');`

`$(".taco")` is your iframe, right?

Comment: is element with class name `url` exist inside your iframe? or even there's more than one? maybe, you must have more specific selector than `'.url'`

Comment: Yes, the page that the iframe loads has a div with the class "url". That is how I am able to add a class to it if it loaded via iframe. I will try another solution. I might delete this if I find it.

Comment: @Divern did you went through the pages link I mentioned on the question comment? Things will get clear if you read those nice posts.

Comment: @Divern I see, but in your later do, you use `.tacoBowl` iframe, not `.taco`, that's why I asked to confirm it. Now there's 2 possibility for the problem, but before, please try `console.log($('.url',$(".taco").contents()).length);`. What appear?

Comment: This was a mistake on mine @TaufikNurRahmanda. Thanks for pointing it out. It worked for me. Thanks!