# How to Access window on Iframe that is inside another iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have issue with accessing iframe that is inside another iframe.
I was trying something like this:

`window.getElementById("parentIframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById("childIframe").contentWindow`

But id did not worked (in my browser console i get something like "Inaccessible")

**I want to know if there is a way to access nested iframe window object ?**

To make things harder top parent window is on different port then iframe content. (So we have CORS to block any access from child iframe content)
Another issue is that i have no way to modify middle iframe content.
I can only embed another iframe inside of it.

**My question is about accessing iframe that is inside another iframe NOT ABOUT CORS reletaed issues.**

Comment: my question is about accessing iframe embeded inside another iframe not about CORS issue.

Comment: @SuperUser Please read my edited question and tell my if it is duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343955/jquery-select-element-inside-iframe-which-is-inside-an-iframe

Comment: @SuperUser Where in my question I am asking about jQuery ???

Comment: You need to access the parent frame ? parent.document.getElementById

Comment: @PhilMaGeo I want to access child window of Iframe that is inside of another iframe from top page so we have something like this <html><iframe><iframe // I Want to access this one ></iframe></iframe></html>

Comment: The opposite is easy. For your concern maybe take a look at the web messaging and window.postMessage. I'm not fluent on the subject but it seems interesting

Comment: @PhilMaGeo thanks for quick answer. I am currently looking on postMessage. I asked this question to find out if someone have better solution.