# If Statement To Check if a Table is contained in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Sorry if this question seems basic, but I cannot find any simple explanations and I'm new to JavaScript, so please give any help/feedback you can.

Basically I have an HTML iframe called `iframe`, and I would like a JavaScript if-statement to see if any `<table>` objects are in it. I don't know exactly how to reference that in the if-statement. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, select element inside iframe, which is inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343955/jquery-select-element-inside-iframe-which-is-inside-an-iframe)

Comment: If the URL of <iframe> is **same origin** (_domain, port, and protocol_), see @Abhinav Manoj 's answer. If not, you can't do it with javascript. (You can try PHP `curl` fetch + AJAX get.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to check whether there is any table in the frame.

For that,
give the iframe an id , like

```
<iframe id ="myFrame">
    <!-- your code goes here -->
</iframe>
```

then in the JavaScript code:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var len = frame.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").length;
if ( len == 0 ){
  // the frame contains no tables
}
else{
   // the frame contains one or more tables
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Mark this as the correct answer so that it will be a help for others

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you usually cannot access the content of an iframe due to [Same Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).